# Node.js Express AJAX GET returns 404

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I have the following:

```
$.get('path/to/file.js', function(data) {
    //this callback function never runs!
});
```

Why isn't the callback being called? :S

Comment: Check your console, is the request going thru? What's Node say about it?

Comment: yes post the output of  console.log(req.url);

Comment: and what does :S mean?

Answer (score 2):

The argument is [for a `success` callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

> jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, **success**(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )

And a `404` ([Not Found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)) response is considered an `error` by jQuery. Generally, only `200` (OK) or the various `3xx` responses are considered "*successes*."

With jQuery 1.5 and later, the jqXHR objects returned from jQuery's Ajax methods implement [`Deferred` objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), so you can use `.fail()` to add such a callback.

```
$.get(...).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('Ajax error', textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

---

If you're wondering why it's getting a `404`, that depends on the actual path used. But, the sample path would be relative to the current page's address.

```
http://yourdomain.tld/foo/bar/page + path/to/file.js =
http://yourdomain.tld/foo/bar/path/to/file.js
```

You might try specifying a relative-to-root path by starting with the `/` after the host, which will use that as a common starting point:

```
$.get('/path/to/file.js', ...);
```

```
http://yourdomain.tld/foo/bar/page + /path/to/file.js =
http://yourdomain.tld/path/to/file.js
```

Comment: Ok. Well it's giving me 200 OK when I access it manually in my browser. For some reason I get 404 when I use AJAX. I'm using node.js with express framework though.

Comment: Actually, it returns 200 OK but with a parseError. So it thinks the JSON is invalid for some reason. However, I took the JSON and went to jsonlint.com and validated the json, jsonlint returns Valid.

Comment: @PetterThowsen Is the JSON from a static file or a route? If it's from a file, what encoding was it saved with? UTF-8 would probably be best. But, does it have a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? If so, see if you can save without it. Or, if it's from a route, does the response include any additional content other than the JSON? How is the JSON generated? Is a `Content-Type` being specified with it?

Comment: Are you making the request on the same box/domain? Otherwise, you'll have to use JSONP as you can't get JS[ON] cross-domain with jQuery.